# I can push notification to one device but fail to push in a loop

Tags: push-notification

I code my push notification service as shown below. It will gain token stored in test_db and then send it. The problem is that I don't receive notification from all my device. But, if I send notification to one specific device and I uncomment `**//if( $row['pushtoken']=='bfd53a383e0f65bc96b43f3547548ec13d4c46d61526d7b6be5d7ed581563e77')**`, the device will receive a notification. It is very weird. Here is my code:

```
$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '111111');
if (!$link) {
    error_log( "mysql_connect fail\n");
    die('could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
else
{
    $is_db_selected = mysql_select_db('test_db',$link);
    if($is_db_selected)
    {
        $sql = "select * from pushtoken;";
        error_log($sql);
        $result = mysql_query($sql, $link);
        if ($result) 
        {
            echo "ready to push notification\n";
            $apnsHost = 'gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com';
            $apnsPort = 2195;
            $apnsCert = 'aps_dev.pem';

            $streamContext = stream_context_create();
            stream_context_set_option($streamContext, 'ssl', 'local_cert', $apnsCert);

            $apns = stream_socket_client('ssl://' . $apnsHost . ':' . $apnsPort, $error, $errorString, 10, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT|STREAM_CLIENT_PERSISTENT , $streamContext);
             if (!$apns)
                exit("Failed to connect: $error $errorString" . PHP_EOL);
            echo 'Connected to APNS' . PHP_EOL;
            ob_flush();
            flush();
            $payload['aps'] = array('alert' => 'xman give mortal 7 messages!!!', 'badge' => 1, 'sound' => 'default');
            $payload = json_encode($payload);
            while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) 
            {
                ***//if( $row['pushtoken']=='bfd53a383e0f65bc96b43f3547548ec13d4c46d61526d7b6be5d7ed581563e77')***
                {
                echo "push notification one by one\n";
                $deviceToken = $row['pushtoken'];
                $apnsMessage = chr(0) . pack("n", 32) . pack('H*',  $deviceToken) .pack("n", strlen($payload)). $payload;
                if(fwrite($apns, $apnsMessage,strlen($apnsMessage))==FALSE)
                {
                    echo "can't write to socket!<br />";
                }
                    ob_flush();
                flush();
                //fclose($apns);
                echo "token is ".$deviceToken ."\n";
                //break;
                }


            }
            //socket_close($apns);
            fclose($apns);
        } else {
            error_log ('error select pushtoken: ' . mysql_error() . "\n");
        }

    }       
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check that all of the tokens are valid. In the past I had an issue where if I had a dev token in my DB and tried to use the production push server all the messages that were sent after the message using the dev token would fail to be delivered.

Comment: all the token is valid, as i try later , i put the stream_socket_client code in the loop it means the connection will reestablished after send one message to one token. In this way , It works. but i don't it is a good way , i need to send package for all token in one ssl connection.